# How to retrieve elements place visually under div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to retrieve an array of images placed under a absolute-positioned div in jQuery or javascript. A sort of selection. I've tried with ".getElementsByPoint", but as it only allows x,y, I'm a little bit confused how I'm gonna incorperate the height and width, and get everything in the area.

Hope someone have some suggestions, to pull me out of my trouble.

I've painted a quick picture to illustrate what I mean.

[image]

Comment: share you `html` code.

Comment: You want all these 4 images in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have answered in pure JS to make the answer relevant in non jQuery environments, but of course with jQuery the selectors can be replaced and the for loop can be replaced with a `.each()`. Additionally if the div is a jQuery draggable or something similar, getSelected function can be made a callback for the div being moved.

Here is the jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/r11h1tjq/2/

If you adjust the absolute position of the div and run, you will see only those images intersecting the div are "selected".

HTML

```
<div id="select"></div>
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="intersect" alt="" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="intersect" alt="" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="intersect" alt="" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="intersect" alt="" />
```

CSS

```
#select {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 175px;
  right: 0;
  border: 3px dashed #000000;
}

.selected {
  border:1px solid #ff0000;
}

img {
  border: 0;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function getSelected() {
  var inBox = []
  var divBox = document.getElementById("select").getBoundingClientRect()
  var images = document.getElementsByClassName("intersect")
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var imageBox = images[i].getBoundingClientRect()
    var overlap = !(divBox.right < imageBox.left ||
      divBox.left > imageBox.right ||
      divBox.bottom < imageBox.top ||
      divBox.top > imageBox.bottom)
    if (overlap) {
      inBox.push(images[i])
    }
  }
  return inBox
}


var selected = getSelected()
for (var j = 0; j < selected.length; j++) {
  selected[j].className += " selected";
}
```

Comment: Thats awesome! Thank you so much, perfect!

Comment: No problem! Also thanks vyz.ca for making my code visible here as well as on the jsFiddle, and the nice placeholders.